# How to add two array object in same array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

For example, I have two array object with different column names and values and I want them to be at same index

```js
let a = [{name: 'asha', age:20, mother: "sushi", father: "Nick"}]
let b = [{class: "10th", Sub: "science", Marks: 30}]
```

and I want to merge these into a single array like this:

```js
[{name: 'asha', age:20, mother: "sushi", father: "Nick", class: "10th", Sub: "science"}]
```

Comment: You have two arrays with only one element each, can they have more than one? because what you ask could be done with just [{...a[0], ...b[0]}]. If they have more than one, how they will merge, the ones with same index?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to combine elements at the same index with spread syntax.

```js
let a = [{name: 'asha', age:20, mother: "sushi", father: "Nick"}], b = [{class: "10th", Sub: "science", Marks: 30, }]
let res = a.map((x, i) => ({...x, ...b[i]}));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both arrays have the same length, you can use a for loop with the spread operator on corresponding elements

```
const combined = [];
for(let i...) {
  combined.push({ ...arr1[i], arr2[i]});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array#forEach` as follows:

```js
const
     a = [{name: 'asha', age:20, mother: "sushi", father: "Nick"}],
     b = [{class: "10th", Sub: "science", Marks: 30}],
     c = [];
     
a.forEach((val, i) => c.push({...val,...b[i]}));

console.log( c );
```